# Ajax post passsing data; not all data is passed. And need type validation

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, jquery

So I am using an ajax post to call an action with my values.
I want to check the types of the functions first and I dont know how to do it.
Also, the ajax post is well called but one of the parameters is null when it should contain the data.

Ajax post:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "AddUpdateConfigs",
    data: ({id: @Model.QueueMonitorConfigurationsID, PathType: $('#ddlConfigTypeName').val(), Threshold:$('#ddlThreshold').val(), ValueType:$('#ddlValueTypeName').val(), Location: $('#txtbLocation').val(), Limit: $('#txtbLimit').val(), config: $('#NewOrUpdate').val() }),
    dataType: JSON
});
```

One of the data I pass is this textbox:

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(cModel => cModel.Value, new { id = "txtbLimit", @type = "int" })
```

Which has to be an int but dont know how to check that or where. I added the `@type` but its not working.

Any ideas?

Comment: why you dont want submit the form with ajax?

Comment: because I dont have a form and dont want to have one

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed:
The name of the parameters in the ajax post and the action parameters has to be the same.

Still don't know how to fix the type validation

Answer (score -1):

Maybe you could use

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(cModel => cModel.Value, new { id = "txtbLimit", @Value = cModel.Value , @type = "int" })
```

or

```
@Html.TextBox("txtbLimit", cModel.Value, new {  @type = "int" })
```

Comment: why should I want to put "text" if I want an 'integer'

Comment: sorry, it was my mistake in copy/paste

Comment: Why should I want to set the value? the value will be what the user puts, not what the model contains